# Page does not smooth scroll, instead it jumps to section

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a website (https://www.metis-online.com) with a call to action and nav bar links along the top of the website. If you click on any of the links, you notice it jumps to the page instead of smooth scrolling to the page. Not sure why it's not smooth scrolling to the relevant anchor link.

My anchor links always have a #. So example it's like:
https://www.metis-online.com/#courses
https://www.metis-online.com/#services
etc

head.php:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $('a[href^="/#"]').on('click', function(event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 800, function(){

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
});

    </script>
```

header.php

```
<!-----NavigationBar---->

<section id="top">
</section>

<section id="nav-bar">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
 
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/../#top">HOME</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/../#about">ABOUT</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/../#courses">COURSES</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/../#services">SERVICES</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/../#testimonials">TESTIMONIALS</a>
              </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/../#contact">CONTACT</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</section>
```

home.php (this is the homepage)

```
<html>

<head>

 <?php include "./head.php" ?>
</head>

<body>

 <?php include "./header.php" ?>

    <!-------About------->
    <section id="about">
    ...
    </section>
    <!-------Courses------->
    <section id="courses">
    ...
    <a href="courses/course-BRFAITC009">
    <button type="button">Order online course and exam bundle</button>
    </a>
    ...
    </section>
    <!-------Services------->
    <section id="services">
    ...
    </section>
    <!-------Testimonials------->
    <section id="testimonials">
    ...
    </section>
    <!-------Contacts------->
    <section id="contacts">
    ...
    </section>

...

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Hi cypherjac and Tudor, it is working now and that is thanks to both your answers combined. For fairness, I will mark one as best answer and upvote the other as you both deserve credit :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tried this in your css?

```css
html{
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
};
```

This will make a smooth transition to the content when you click on the navbar links.

Comment: Actually the animation is supposed to run as expected regardless of this setting

Comment: this trick with scroll behavior looks good on browser and is easy to use it in my opinion.

Comment: Yes I did try this yesterday whilst trying to fix it but no luck

Comment: Got is working, can you see comment under question please

Answer (score 2):

Try removing this **strict** equality check:

```
if (this.hash !== "") {
// Prevent default anchor click behavior
event.preventDefault();
```

And change it to:

```
if (this.hash != "") { ...
```

---

Your problem is right here:

```
$('a[href^="/#"]').on('click', ...
```

This line looks for an anchor beginning with "/" instead of "#", change it to:

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', ...
```

Comment: Hi Cypherjac, it did not seem to make a difference when I tried the above answer

Comment: Got is working, can you see comment under question please

Comment: Ok, but also check my edit, there was a problem with the anchor validation